# Upgrading to SQL Server Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqlperformance

We have a huge SSIS load each night on SQL server (Version Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3370.1 (X64) standard edition. We have 192 GB RAM installed on the server and the OS is Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. The processor is a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6234 CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3292 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s).

Our SSIS flow is running around 8 hours every night (from 00.00 - 08.00). Could it give us some additional performance improvements if we upgrade the SQL server to Enterprise edition?

Anybody has some experience with an upgrade like that? The license cost for the Enterprise edition, is significantly higher than the standard edition cost, so we want to make sure, that we will get an equal significantly performance improvement.

We have no performance issues when we are doing normal queries on the database, it is only during the nightly SSIS flow.

We have of course already tried to optimize our SSIS and TSQL, so we are looking into other ways to improve our flow.

Comment: It is impossible to answer without knowing how the SSIS works and without identify the bottlenecks.

Comment: There is a dedicated SE for Database Administration. You might get better feedback on that SE with regards to this question.

Comment: The bottlenecks are mostly memory related. If we try to execute to many packages at the same time, we get the memory error "A timeout occurred while waiting for a memory resource to execute the query in resource pool". We are also making sure that our 3-4 most consuming packages are not running at the same time.

Comment: If you can parallel process then a better solution to look into might be scaling out aka running multiple instances of SQL Server Standard on multiple machines. Or go Azure Cloud route to minimise costs running instances.

Comment: `The bottlenecks are mostly memory related.` and `We have 192 GB RAM` are self-contradictory. To get problems with so much RAM the *queries* and flows must be exceptionally bad, loading everything into RAM instead of processing and transforming the data as a stream. The whole point of using a Dataflow is that the data is processed as a stream of items that are transformed by each step.

Comment: I suspect the SSIS packages use complex queries instead of streaming data. Those queries are executed by the database, no matter what client tool issues them. If there are missing indexes, non-SARGable conditions, expressions that require scanning an an entire table, the database will have to buffer all the data and spill into `tempdb`. That's a query problem, not a database problem. Upgrading won't fix bad queries

Comment: Of course, we are not missing any indexes, and the queries are optimized. We are creating more than 1.000.000.000 rows in total. Divided into around 40 different Customer Databases as Fact and Dimension tables. The reason why I say memory related, is that, even though we have 192 GB RAM, we still get the memory error with the timeout issue to the resource pool.

Comment: Enabling **buffer pool extension** and placing it on an Optane or other fast SSD is one option to try.  No extra licensing fees.